# Get rectangular contours from image

Tags: c++, opencv

How to extract all rectangular contours from an image with a black background?

I want to get the black rectangle in the bottom (with some white text inside)

In the code I try to fetch all contours via `cv::RETR_EXTERNAL` with 4 corners, but it only fetches the whole image as one big contour?? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    std::cout << "contour found" << std::endl;

    std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
    cv::approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, cv::arcLength(contours[i], true) * 0.02, true);

    if(!cv::isContourConvex(approx)){
        continue;
    }

    if(approx.size() == 4){
        cv::rectangle(img, cv::boundingRect(contours[i]), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }
}

cv::imwrite("img.png", img);
```

[image]

Comment: If your images are always like this, then you can filter out the contours by calculating ratio of black and non black pixels. Also limit the findcontours function to the lower half  or lower 1/3 of  image, to get faster results.

Comment: The images are always different so you can't really do that :)

Comment: You have asked several of these questions in the past and IMO you don't really care about how to get the results by discussing some plausible results or help that the people who answer/comment on your question but just the final result. I don't really see a point in putting same questions again and again without reassessing the previous answers you've gotten

Comment: @RickM. I have not enough experience with opencv (or C++) to put some code together from plain descriptions and teory

Comment: If I ask for a little help to put some code together I just get the response that I have to do it myself.. which I can't..

Comment: @clarkk That is perfectly understandable. In this question for example, you haven't show any efforts of trying to find what you are looking for and I don't mean by code but by ideas. I am very sure that there are questions like this which will give you the correct directions. In any case, consider adding at least a few more cases on how the images change so we can present a general solution.

Comment: In my example I look for rectangular contours which is convex.. but that doesn't work as expected.. If that isn't working I can't go further

Comment: @clarkk Srill you can filter out using the ratio of black and non black pixels, You visualise all contours and then contours after filtering, you will get a good threshold value for filtering out using ratio of black and nonblack pixels

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari yes I need to do some black/white ratio when I have found the contours.. But my code doesn't fetch the contours.. it just thinks the whole image is a contour

Comment: @clarkk Try inverting the image and [read the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) _The object to be found should be white on a black background_

Comment: I answered my own question yesterday with the same solution :)

Comment: @RickM. but maybe you have a solution for this one? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352707/how-to-absdiff-a-grayscale-image-with-a-mask-in-cv-8uc1

Answer (score 1):

Found out I need to invert the image before I can use `cv::RETR_EXTERNAL`

```
img_inv = 255 - img;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong flag:

cv::RETR_EXTERNAL : If you use this flag, it returns only extreme outer flags. All child contours are left behind

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

You should use cv::RETR_LIST,because you need all the contours and you do not need the hierarchy.

Comment: I found out I need to invert the image before it will work.. but you mentioned to get the black/white ratio of the contours.. how would you calculate the ratio? :)