# How to absdiff() a grayscale image with a mask in CV_8UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

`invert_mask` is CV_8UC1 with some filled contours (pixel value 255) and `src` is grayscale

I want to invert the colors under the mask in `src`

The ouput image almost looks right except for the areas under the mask.. They are just black. It looks like only the white color is turned to black but the black color stays black

I don't want to binarize the `src` image because I have to do some processing on it after this

```
cv::absdiff(invert_mask, 255 - src, src);
src = 255 - src;
```

If I do this the white color is converted to black but the black/gray color is untouched

```
cv::absdiff(invert_mask, src, src);
```

## src

[image]

## invert_mask

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some example image, and your desired output? From your explanation, and your code I get a result, I would call correct.

Comment: have added `src` and `invert_mask` image

Comment: And your expected output? If I run your code, the nearly-white text inside the mask becomes nearly-black. The (nearly 128) gray box around this text becomes a (nearyl 128) gray box again. So, from my point of view, there is no error!?

Comment: I want the gray rectangle to become white and the white text to become black (or gray)

Comment: I want to invert the colors under the mask :) So white becomes black and black becomes white

Comment: is it possible to apply `THRESH_OTS` in the areas under the mask before doing absdiff?

Comment: "I want the gray rectangle to become white and the white text to become black (or gray)" - that's NOT (simple) inverting. To put it very simple, inverting is: White <-> Black, "bright" gray <-> "dark gray". You want some kind of custom color replacement.

Comment: check my previous comment.. is it possible to apply `THRESH_OTSU` on the area under the mask before absdiff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired color replacement, the following short snippet using simple thresholding should do the trick:

```cpp
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("src.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat invert_mask = cv::imread("invert_mask.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::Mat textInMask = src.clone().mul(invert_mask / 255);
    cv::threshold(textInMask, textInMask, 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::Mat output = src.clone() + invert_mask - textInMask;
```

Output image:

[image]

The quality may be improved, this is just the basic concept.